# Migrate to Standard SQL: choose the closest sunday from current date

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I need to migrate from **legacy** to **standard SQL** this query:

```
SELECT MAX(FECHA)
FROM(
SELECT FECHA, DAYOFWEEK(FECHA) AS DIA
FROM(
SELECT DATE(DATE_ADD(TIMESTAMP("2017-05-29"), pos - 1, "DAY")) AS FECHA
FROM (
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS pos, *
     FROM (
       FLATTEN((
         SELECT SPLIT(RPAD('', 1 + DATEDIFF(TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE()), 
         TIMESTAMP("2017-05-29")), '.'),'') AS h
         FROM (SELECT NULL)),h
)))
))
WHERE DIA=1
```

The query must return the previous closest sunday date from current date.

When I run this in standard SQL I get

> Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")" at [12:2] (after FROM (SELECT NULL)),h

Comment: What have you tried? What error do you get when you run this? Have you read this? https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/migrating-from-legacy-sql

Comment: This query works into Legacy SQL. No messages error appears. I need to migrate it into standard SQL, and I don't know how to deal with this language

Comment: So when you run it in Standard SQL What error message do you get?

Comment: Syntax error: Expected keyword JOIN but got ")" at [12:2] (after FROM (SELECT NULL)),h

Comment: I will add this to your question. In future, please do this in the first instance

Comment: what if the date already is a Sunday? Should it then be that date, or 7 days ago?

Comment: The query is programmed to run always on Mondays

Comment: from Monday it would always be "yesterday"?

Comment: AT FIRST THE QUERIES ARE SCHEDULED FOR MONDAYS, BUT IT MAY BE TO BE DELAYED. NOTHING THE IDEAL IS TO MAKE THE DIFERENCE BETWEEN THE CURRENT_DATE () AND THE WEEKDAY (), TO MOVE THE DATES OF THE END OF DATE RANGE QUERY TO SUNDAY

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The query must return the previous closest sunday date from current date.

```
#standardSQL
SELECT 
  DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL EXTRACT(DAYOFWEEK FROM CURRENT_DATE()) - 1 DAY)
```

You can replace `CURRENT_DATE()` with any date and it will return previous closest Sunday

Comment: Thanks a lot @Mikhail Berlyant

Answer (score 2):

You can use `DATE_TRUNC` with the `WEEK` part to truncate to the most recent Sunday. For example:

```
#standardSQL
WITH Input AS (
  SELECT date
  FROM UNNEST([
    DATE '2017-06-26',
    DATE '2017-06-24',
    DATE '2017-05-04']) AS date
)
SELECT
  date,
  FORMAT_DATE('%A', date) AS dayofweek,
  DATE_TRUNC(date, WEEK) AS previous_sunday
FROM Input;
```

This returns:

```
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
|    date    | dayofweek | previous_sunday |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
| 2017-06-24 | Saturday  |      2017-06-18 |
| 2017-05-04 | Thursday  |      2017-04-30 |
| 2017-06-26 | Monday    |      2017-06-25 |
+------------+-----------+-----------------+
```